# How can I view a portfolio's historical performance?

Tags: investing, portfolio, historical-data

I have a premium Morningstar subscription. It provides a wealth of information and is mostly enough for my information needs.

I'm able to create portfolios and watchlists, and watch their performance since the time I created the portfolio or watchlist.

But it doesn't seem to be possible to view **historical performance of a portfolio** or watchlist. I can view the historical performance of an individual security or performance of a portfolio/watchlist since I created it, but not the historical performance of a portfolio/watchlist.

Is there any resource that allows you to view the historical performance of a portfolio? That would be great for seeing how it, as a whole, performed during different market conditions, and whether you need to make any changes to the portfolio of securities before you buy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, further, I was able to find [Portfolio Visualizer](https://www.portfoliovisualizer.com/backtest-portfolio), a very cool tool!

I hope this helps anyone else looking for the same thing.